# Searching for a large number of extensions with find

Tags: files, find

I'm looking to create a baseline of file extensions and then search for the inverse of them (essentially scanning for new extensions and then reporting on them).

I have:

```
base_file=`find "/volume1/" -type f | grep -E ".*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" | sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/' | sort | uniq -u`
```

to create my baseline - the initial search of the files on the volume.

For a small amount of files, using

```
find $dir -type f \( -not -name "foo*" -and -not -name "*bar" \)
```

worked wonderfully.  Alas, I have tons of files, though.  If I pipe every unique extension into the `find` command, it does not work (understandably).

Ex. of output:

```
.acx .adb .aex .agt .ahs .alt .amsorm .ANI .ARTX .ASAX .ASDefs .asmdot .ASMDOT .ASPX .atb .atm .aus .auth .authd .awk .ben .Bin .BIO .bkp .bms .boo .bootstrap .bplist .bridgesupport .bto .btt .CBK .ccp .cd .cdm .cdrom .CFGOLD .cfm .cfp .CFS .cg .cidb .cilk .clk .cmptag .CMValidateMovieDataReferenceService .ColorSyncXPCAgent .common .con .CONFIG .COR .cpi .cpu .crc .crdownload .crmlog .cryptodev .csh .ctd .ctl .cue .cws .d .daeexportpreset .daeimportpreset .DATA .dbg .DBG .dbl .DCD .DCX .debug .defaults .defltools .defmtools .der .desktop .dfont .DGDLL .DGN .DictionaryServiceHelper .dig .django .dla .dlb .dlh .dlk .dLL .dlmp .DLO .DMP .DNP .dps .DriverHelper .DRWDOT .dsd .dtc .DTL .dwd .dwfx .dwG .e .eai .eapol .EDB .edc .edited .ENC .eng .ENV .epub .erl .esi .esm .EVM .EVP .ews .example .exv .fac .fatal .fbk .FBK .fbT .FCL .fe .file .fin .fl .FLL .font .FontDownloadHelper .for .fpk .fre .frT .FW .FXP .gadget .Gadget .gdb .generic .ger .gi .glo .gm .gpx .groovy .group .gsl .gss .gws .GZ .ham .hbs .hd .hidden .hkf .hpdata .hs .htb .HTT .hun .hx .hxd .hxx .HXX .IBM .ICNS .igb .IGS .iHB .imaging .IME .IMG .in .INP .install .Installsettings .int .IPConfiguration .IPMonitor .ITK .ITS .iuf .java .jnilib .job .JPEG .jqx .kd .keychainproxy .keys .kondo .krn .kscript .ksh .lfs .libraries .LID .lisp .liveReg .local .LOCAL .lok .lppi .lsl .lt .ltools .mak .mako .mapping .mappings .mas .masm .matlab .mbr .mch .MDE .mdmp .mdw .me .med .MediaLibraryService .mem .mholders .MIF .MIG .min .mk .mm .mno .mobileconfig .mom .mp .MPE .mpq .MPV .mpx .MPX .msdb .MSDefs .msilog .MSM .MSP .mtools .mup .nasm .netsa .new .nfm .nlog .nor .nsi .ntd .numbers .nut .nv .nvv .NWD .O .oai .oct .Ocx .oft .ogv .older .omo .ooc .openAndSavePanelService .ori .orignal .osf .override .pad .page .partial .pas .patch .pbb .pch .Pdf .PDFFileRefsValidator .pdn .PDR .pexe .pfw .phar .pif .pike .pix .PJT .PJX .PLS .plsql .po .pokki .pot .ppf .ppk .pptm .preferences .PRG .prm .PRN .pro .propdesc .prtdot .PRTDOT .prx .PSDefs .PST .psw .pta .ptb .ptg .python .r .rayhosts .rc .rcd .RCF .rd .RecentPictureService .regcccc .registerassistantservice .RLA .rnd .rpk .RPW .RSC .rst .rupldb .rus .salog .sap .SAP .sbt .sbx .sbxx .SCH .schemas .scm .SCR .sct .SDP .sds .sdu .Search .securityd .SEP .set .setup .Setuplog .SFV .sfx .sgi .sgn .sidb .sidd .sigs .sites .skin .slddrt .smc .SMC .smf .smilebox .SOL .spdc .speechsynthesisd .spn .sqfs .squashfs .srt .srx .ssi .st .ste .stg .styx .swb .swtag .TAR .TDC .tdf .tex .th .tib .time .tips .tmx .tpg .tpm .trace .transformed .trm .TSK .tst .Txt .txz .type .udf .ufm .ult .uninstall .upd .upstart .urf .user .User .UserDictionary .UserProfile .UserScriptService .usr .ux .v .vala .values .var .VAR .vbe .VBR .vcs .vcxproj .vdb .vdf .VERSION .VersionsUIHelper .vhdl .vms .vmsn .vmss .VOL .voucher .vps .vsb .vst .vvv .wax .wbt .Wdf .webp .WIZ .wnt .WPT .ws .wsc .wsdl .WSF .wsp .xap .xht .XLL .xlS .XLT .xmp .xpfwext .xtext .yaml .zipx .zz
```

How can I search for all of these, or inverse of, without running into issues?  Or, more importantly, is there a better solution for this type of task?

Comment: You don't need to use grep and sed. Just use sed with `/pattern/` syntax. (I think you might not even need that since the `s///` section already has your regex.)

Comment: Backticks are deprecated. Use `$()` instead. And quote the process substitution. This is Bash, right? Not Bourne?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep`'s `-f` option that allows you to search for a list of patterns stored in a file:

```
# find "$dir" -type f | grep -f ext_patterns.txt
```

Here file `ext_patterns.txt` must contain extensions as regex, like:

```
\.html$
\.java$
\.jpg$
```

You can create that file the same way you create your baseline. Here is a command using `awk`:

```
find -type f -name "*.*" \
| awk -F. '{ print "\\." $NF "$" }' \
| sort -u \
> ext_patterns.txt
```

Here `find` output filenames having an extension; `awk` prints the extension along with a leading (escaped) dot and a final `$` (regex code meaning "end of line"); and `sort -u` makes each pattern unique.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have GNU find or FreeBSD/macOS find, you can construct a large regular expression that matches all the patterns, and list files using `-regex`. Beware that constructing the regular expression is not straightforward: you need to take care of special characters in the extensions. Your current code is already not doing anything sensible if a file name's extension contains a newline. With GNU tools, you can do (untested)

```
new_extensions=$(find / -regextype posix-extended -name '*.*' -type f ! -regex "$old_regex" -print0 |
                 sed -z 's/.*\.//; s/[][\\$^.()|*+?]/\\&/g' |
                 sort -zu | tr '\0' '|')
if [ "$new_extensions" = "|" ]; then
  echo "No new extensions"
else
  new_regex="\\.(${new_extensions%?})\$"
fi
```

I think you'll be better off with a perl/python/ruby script. You can start off with `find2perl` or use Python's `os.walk`.